# Why is the answering threshold lower than the comment threshold?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, reputation, privileges

Straight forward question. The threshold for commenting is higher than the threshold for answering. Why is that? In my mind, it makes sense for commenting to come before answering. (Or at least at the same time)

Let's say you find a question that someone else has answered, but you have a slightly improved version (maybe theirs with a small modification such as a fixed typo). You can make a completely new answer that is mostly somebody elses, but you can't comment on theirs and say "missed a semi-colon" or something. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You can suggest an edit.  There should be additional characters that you can change so that you can enter a suggestion, in the case where a single character addition is needed for correct syntax.

Comment: To correct mistakes/typos use suggested edits; answers should only be used for addressing OP's question. Answering has lower threshold because it is Q and A site, anybody can contribute an answer, it's survival depends on the quality though. And writing good answers is a good way to earn unicorn points for a new user.

Answer (score 7):

Answering is a core function of the site, and answers come equipped with a wider range of actions that other users can use to moderate them.

Comments have very few handles and are in any case strictly secondary to the mission of the site.

Comment: I politely disagree, not only Answering, Comments are almost* mandatory characteristic to downvote, that's what maintain SO with good quality answers. *(Almost because you can downvote without commenting but you get "-1")

Comment: @Gödel: You can comment before you can downvote. Also, you get the -1 on downvoting an answer (no penalty on questions!) regardless of any comments you leave.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's what I said, comments are ALMOST mandatory, so that you can downvote without commenting but that's punished with -1.

Answer (score 1):

I agree.. comment rights should come slightly before answer rights. I've seen too many NAAs with the explanation, "But I *can't* comment!".

Comments are a transient, easily deletable part of the site. As @dmckee said, they are strictly secondary to the main content of the site.

We should let new users cut their teeth on those first. *Then* they will be ready for more responsibility, such as answering questions and eventually, moderation. It seems to be a natural progression to me.

Comment: I agree totally!

Comment: This is pretty much my view on it, too. Hence why I asked. :P